# Makefile: how to detect changes within the makefile itself?

Tags: makefile

I'm aware of the idea of using recursive makefiles. Will the subsequent makefiles such as the following be called be updated solely on any changes to the subsequent makefiles themselves?

e.g.:

```
#parent makefile. no changes here. 
subsystem:
    cd subdir && $(MAKE)
```

If the makefile within subdir was changed such that the following does not hold (e.g. only a gcc flag was changed), then will the object files be updated?

> The recompilation must be done if the source file, or any of the
>   header files named as dependencies, is more recent than the object
>   file, or if the object file does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason that, as written, make even runs that rule at all is because `subsystem` and `subdir` do not match.

If a `subsystem` file or directory were ever to be created in that directory that rule would cease to function.

If `.PHONY: subsystem`<sup>[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets)</sup> were added that problem would be fixed and that rule would **always** be run when listed on the command line (i.e. `make subsystem`). (As indicated in the comments `.PHONY` is a GNU Make extension. The section following the linked section discusses a portable alternative. Though it is worth noting that they are not completely identical in that `.PHONY` has some extra benefits and some extra limitations.)

In neither of those cases is the `subsystem` target paying any attention to modification dates of anything (as it lists no prerequisites).

To have a target depend on changes to a makefile you need to list the makefile(s) as prerequisites like anything else (i.e. `subsystem: subdir/Makefile`). Listing it as `.PHONY` is likely more correct and more what you want.

No, nothing in make itself tracks non-prerequisites. So flag changes/etc. do not trigger rebuilds. There are ways to make that work for make however (they involve storing the used flags in files that themselves are prerequisites of the targets that use those flags, etc.). There are questions and answers on SO about doing that (I don't have them ready offhand though).

Other tools do handle flag changes automatically however. I believe [Electric Cloud](http://electric-cloud.com/)'s tools do this. I believe [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) does as well. There might also be others.

Comment: `.PHONY` is useful, but you might want to mention that it's an extension in GNU make but not present generally in make implementations.

Comment: Wait, if you mention a makefile as a prerequisite, won't it detect if there are any changes whatsoever to that targeted makefile? More specifically, if you change a flag within a recipe of the targeted makefile, does that makefile run entirely or simply enter and exit it without actually doing anything? (You implied the latter). This is considering the entire build is complete, and only a flag in one recipe is changed (no targets within the makefiles are changed except the targeted makefile itself. "No, nothing in make itself tracks non-prerequisites." got me confused.

Comment: @imagineerThat Modify (for make's purposes) the makefile listed as a prerequisite and it will trigger any targets that list it as a prerequisite, yes. Just like a normal prerequisite does. make isn't smart enough to know *which* target you modified though (if there are several in the modified makefile). Changing a flag, however, will not cause targets that *use* that flag to be rebuilt if none of the target prerequisites have changed.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive makefiles are executed whether or not anything changed.  This is exactly one of the objections pointed out by Paul Miller in his [Recursive make considered harmful](https://web.archive.org/web/20150319074420/http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) paper from almost 20 years ago.

With that said, a makefile is just like any other dependency and can be added to a production rule to trigger that rule if the makefile is altered.

Comment: Great read. Using a single makefile seems like a well thought out solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can include the makefile as a dependency, the same as any other file:

```
mytarget.o: mytarget.c Makefile
```

Comment: In this case, will any textual changes within the dependency Makefile be detected?

Comment: @imagineerThis Yes, this will trigger a rebuild here for **any** change to the makefile. Relevant to this target or not.

Comment: @EtanReisner is correct - it is not possible (even theoretically) to tell if there were changes to a given TARGET, since we don't know what the makefile said when the last compile happened.

Comment: It is possible to know that but you need to explicitly record all the relevant information. Which is what, to one extent or another, the tools that track this (that I mentioned in my answer) do.

Comment: If you simply make sure all the makefiles in your project are specified as prereqs transitively up to the initial "parent" makefile, then aren't you covered for all *textual* changes to all the makefiles? The only issue is then is the case if there are no textual changes, but targets within a sub makefile are changed, then that makefile won't run.